# How to get a specific list from a list of lists?

Tags: r, list

This is such a basic question and for some reason I can't figure out how to get this right. Suppose I have a list of lists

```
v <- list(
          list(a=1, b=2, c=3), 
          list(a=4, b=5, c=6), 
          list(a=7, b=8, c=9))
```

How do I pull out a list of all elements that are named "a". i.e. I would like to get `list(1, 4, 7)` asking for `a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `pluck`

```
library(tidyverse)
map(v, pluck, "a")
#[[1]]
#[1] 1

#[[2]]
# [1] 4

#[[3]]
# [1] 7
```

---

The corresponding method in `base R` would be

```
lapply(v, `[[`, "a")
```

Comment: @Denis You can just load `library(purrr)`

Answer (score 1):

In base R, we can use

```
unlist(v)[names(unlist(v))=="a"]
```

Or, if your prefer not to use `unlist` twice:

```
(x <- unlist(v))[names(x)=="a"]
```

Comment: I was going to mark this as an answer because it's really good. I just can't mark both answers as an answer. I like that this is so simple.